# Why is an app running under Tomcat using only half of the available CPUs?

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, windows-server-2008

I have a 3rd party Java app that's running under Tomcat under Win2008 R2 64-bit.  It's a multi-threaded app that exposes its API via a SOAP service.

When I look at the Task Manager Performance tab, it looks like it's only using 4 out of 8 cores, regardless of how much load I throw at it.  The vendor of the application swears up and down that they are not doing anything that would affect the CPU usage like this (and they are not seeing it on their end).

I've done the following:

- Checked affinity of the tomcat6.exe - it's using all processors.
- Checked to make sure that the Java service is actually receiving all the requests - it does.
- Looked in every .conf file in the tomcat directory, but didn't see anything relevant (also this is my first involvement with Tomcat - so, I don't really know what I am looking for).
- Tried it under both Java 1.5 and 1.6 on 2 different servers - same result.

Some hardware is as follows:
2 Xeon E5606 @ 2.13 Ghz processors with 4 cores each.
72 GB of RAM - 24GB allocated to Tomcat.

Why is the Java app using only half the cores?

Comment: I can imagine you already discarded that there is a block on disk I/O?

Comment: @Luis I didn't think there was since all the work is being done on datasets in memory, but I found this almost identical [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734229/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-use-more-than-1-cpu), that states that logging framework in use is slowing everything down.  If it does, I'll close this question as being a dup.

Comment: Sounds like Tomcat is using only one physical processor, hard to say why though. See if this is of any help: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#perf_scaling

Comment: Have you tried to run a dummy app in the same JVM that tries to fully load the same amount of threads that you have cores?

Comment: @Luis Nope, it was not the I/O.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running this JSP in the same JVM to test if all cores are used:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%

class ThreadLoad implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        long result = 0;
        // increase the amount of loops until sufficient load
        for (long dummy = 0; dummy < 100000000; dummy++) {
            if (dummy % 2 == 0)
                result += dummy;
            else
                result -= dummy;
        }
    }
}

int cpus = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
Thread[] threads = new Thread[cpus];

for (int i = 0; i < cpus; i++) {
    threads[i] = new Thread(new ThreadLoad());
    threads[i].start();
}

for (int i = 0; i < cpus; i++) {
    threads[i].join();
}

response.getWriter().println("Done");

%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I get the following error: `The method run() of type ThreadLoad must override a superclass method`

Comment: Try adding this to the top `<%@ page import="java.lang.Runnable,java.lang.Thread,java.lang.Runtime" %>`

Comment: Actually, removing @Override did the trick.  Thanks.  Tomcat is fine - it pegged all CPUs.  Must be an issue with vendor's software.

Comment: Looks like it. Good luck with the vendor.